# Element not found in Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I keep getting this error:

```
Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       cannot fill in, no text field, text area or password field with id, name, or label 'Morning' found.
```

I've reset spork, done a full db reset, tried assigning an ID to the form element, etc.  What could possibly be the issue here?

**`days_controller_spec.rb`**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe DaysController do

  describe "New" do

    describe "with valid information" do

      it "should create a new entry" do
        visit 'days#new'
        fill_in "Morning", with: "Test"
        click_button "Submit"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**`days_controller.rb`**

```
<%= form_for @day do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :morning %>
  <%= f.text_field :morning %>

  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Did you add a `save_and_open_page` command just to make sure you're at the right page?

Comment: @mdepolli Yep, it's navigating to the correct page.  I just created the app.  This form page is one of the two pages created so far.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you app is using JavaScript. With capybara you need to add `:js => true` option to the block that's dealing with JS pages.

Try:

```
it "should create a new entry", :js => true do
```

You may also need to way for the form to be rendered before trying to `fill_in` the field.

Also, I recommend you check out capybara's integration DSL. Read more about it [here](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara)

Comment: Turns out the ":js => true" wasn't the answer, but your mentioning "integration" made me remember to try putting the test in an integration test spec.  Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that syntax was all correct, but the issue was that the test was in the wrong RSpec spec file.  When I swapped this test into an integration_test file, it worked perfectly.